# Closures with PHP

Tags: php, closures

I have a weird problem trying to use closures in PHP. When assigning a closure to a variable, I get a `null` value. But when displaying the closure with `var_dump()`, everything is alright.

Here is a source code that summarizes the problem:

```
$f = function() {};
var_dump($f); // 'null'

var_dump(function() {}); // 'object(Closure)[1]'
```

I'm using PHP 5.3.1.

Edit: I forgot to mention, I have this problem only when I'm using PHP via Apache. I don't have issues when using PHP CLI.

Comment: but according to 3v4l.. it works.. weird. http://3v4l.org/SFd06

Comment: Weird. I'm getting [this output](http://3v4l.org/SFd06) (which is the correct one, AFAIK).

Comment: Try running that code exactly, to be sure your summary isn't different from your actual code.

Comment: John, this source code actually gives me this output.

Comment: I have no idea then, hopefully someone will have an answer for you.

Comment: Regardless of the error *(obvious bug)*, **I don't think there's any reason to have an empty `Closure`**. Just use a `null` and verify if `is_callable` before using it. *PS: It's fixed in `5.5.1`.*

Comment: @CodeAngry If it's a bug, the least you could do is share the actual bug number or something.

Comment: @Jack **It must be a bug. Because I just ran the code on 5.5.1 and it works as expected. So it's... FIXED.** - *hence it was a bug, logic says so*. Unfortunately, I'm too busy to do bug research at the moment. And this bug would never hit me as I see absolutely no reason in writing an empty closure. I usually write functions that do stuff.

Comment: @CodeAngry Did you see the [3v4l link](http://3v4l.org/SFd06) that was mentioned earlier? The (correct) output is identical from 5.3 onwards (when closures were introduced), so if it is indeed a bug it's highly specific to the setup that was used, so even your setup could be different.

Comment: @Jack **You were right!** It's a BUG, but not in PHP... *It's hard to imagine I was commenting on a question of someone who never used Closures before on his setup... so I take all questions seriously.* #still-shocked

Answer (score 2):

A colleague found the answer to the problem: the responsible is **eAccelerator**! Apparently it's not compatible with PHP 5.3 closures... [(source)](https://github.com/eaccelerator/eaccelerator/issues/12)

Disabling it solved the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Consider updating. They claim to support 5.4 on their site.** PS: Is the first time you use a closure...? *They're probably the most useful PHP feature added this decade and they've been around for ONLY 4 years.*

Comment: If it depended on me I'll always use PHP 5.4 or 5.5, but I'm using in professional environment...

Answer (score 0):

It's either a very rare (and already fixed) bug or you're not showing the exact same usage that gives you a NULL. My guess is that you're doing this with the first `var_dump()`:

```
var_dump($f());
```

Note the parenthesis, they cause the function to be run and therefore you get its return value.

Comment: Nope, I copy-pasted the code. When I write `$f()` I have an error. (It's logic since `$f` is evaluated to null.)